# How to parse this particular html?

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
<span class="ClassName @variable" title="ClassName @variable">Variable Title</span>
```

"ClassName", "variable" & "Variable Title" are paramerters.

Now I want to extract the "ClassName", "variable" and "Variable Title" from that sentence. How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I have some problem that prevent using the code tag.

Comment: Which language are you using to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript:

```
var matches = /<span class="(.*)" title="(.*)">(.*)<\/span>/.exec(str);
```

Where `str` is your tag.

Then...

```
matches[1]=class
matches[2]=title
matches[3]=tag content
```

Note that you should really use a proper HTML parser for this kind of thing rather than Regex but never mind :)

Comment: @El Ronnoco: Your regex help me out. Thanks!

Comment: @philonous: in this case, I just need to parse that one sentence, so that I think using a HTML parser is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.10.1;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = q!<span class="ClassName @variable" title="ClassName @variable">Variable Title</span>!;
my @list = $str =~ m#<span class="(\w+) @(\w+).*?>([\w\s]+)</span>#;

say Dumper \@list;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'ClassName',
          'variable',
          'Variable Title'
        ];
```

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunaly I can't test the regex using Perl.